# If C/A is abelian, then C/B is abelian.

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to prove that if groups A $\lhd$ B $\lhd$ C, A $\lhd$ C,  and C/A is abelian, then C/B and B/A are abelian.

Clearly, B/A is abelian since it is a subgroup of the abelian group C/A. However, I am having a hard time proving C/B is abelian. I also cannot seem to find a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: using the first isomorphism theorem you can prove that $C/B \cong (C/A)/(B/A)$.

Also note that $B/A$ is a normal subgroup of $C/A$ because $B$ is normal in $C$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The fact that $C/A$ is Abelian means that if $x,y\in C$, there is an $a\in A$ such that $xy=yxa$ (why?). Now use the fact that $A\subseteq B$.